# Get string between two spacial character and space

Tags: php

i get string between two spacial character and space.

this is my string **"%-25% Asdasd asasa"**

I get **"-25"**

I try this like

```
$s = %-25% Asdasd asasa;
$matches = [];
$t = preg_match('/\%(.*)\%/', $s, $matches);
```

Comment: what is the problem then???

Comment: i can't get "-25"....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $s = "%-25% Asdasd asasa";
    $matches = array();
    $t = preg_match('/%(.*?)\%/s', $s, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
    exit;
```

Comment: I also compare "%space"

Comment: you try this string "%-25%Asdasd asasa"

Comment: got exact -25, do you want anything else?

Comment: i not get "-25" when this string "%-25%Asdasd asasa"

Comment: you try this one `$t = preg_match('/%(.*?)\%\s/', $s, $matches);`

Comment: but output not get when "%space" not availabel

Comment: Please use  $t = preg_match('/%(.*?)\%/s', $s, $matches);   which I have provided you above

Comment: i try first  `$t = preg_match('/%(.*?)\%/s', $s, $matches);`  this preg_match

Comment: but this preg_match give correct output `$t = preg_match('/%(.*?)\%\s/', $s, $matches);`

Comment: but for me  $t = preg_match('/%(.*?)\%/s', $s, $matches); working well for every scenario...is it solved now?

Comment: i not get "-25" when the string is "%-25%Asdasd asasa"